# Email Attachment Download Performance and Task Cancelled Issue

Tags: c#, performance, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments

I am using below code to get attachments from email. But have following issues. I am using Graph API nuget version 4.18.0

1. When the attachments size is larger it takes time to download. I understand that will be true but looking for ways if any optimizations can be done.
2. Almost every few emails processed, I am getting below errors at the above line of code mentioned, what could be the reason for this?

Appreciate any insights/suggestions to fix the issues.

**Code:**

```
   inboxMessage = await graphClient
                        .Users[MailUser]
                        .MailFolders
                        .Inbox
                        .Messages
                        .Request()
                        .Top(5)
                        .OrderBy("receivedDateTime ASC")                        
                        .GetAsync();
                                                
foreach (var message in inboxMessage.CurrentPage.ToList())
                    {

                    //Processing messages code not copied.
                    //Below line of code errors with the error message reported.
var attachments = await graphClient
                      .Users[MailUser]
                      .Messages[message.Id].Attachments
                      .Request()
                      .GetAsync();
                      
                      
                      foreach (var emailobj in attachments)
                            {
                                //Processing attahments
                            }
                    }
```

**Error When Above code is executed:**

```
Message: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.MessageAttachmentsCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at GraphPOC.EmailMain.<GetDataAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
Category: Error
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
Title:
App Domain: GraphPOC.exe
ProcessId: 988
Process Name: D:\Program Files\GraphPOC.exe
Thread Name: 
Win32 ThreadId:4884
Extended Properties: 
    Callstack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache.get_Callstack()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.WriteFooter(TraceEventCache eventCache)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedTextWriterTraceListener.TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, Object data)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener.TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, Object data)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource.TraceData(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, LogEntry logEntry, TraceListenerFilter traceListenerFilter)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.ProcessLog(LogEntry log)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.Write(LogEntry log)
   at GraphPOC.EmailMain.<GetDataAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.MessageAttachmentsCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SetTaskCanceled(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<StartContentBuffering>b__0(Task contentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(Task task, Boolean needsProtection)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.TrySetException(Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<LoadIntoBufferAsync>b__0(Task copyTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(Task task, Boolean needsProtection)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.TrySetException(Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamAsyncResult.Complete(Object result)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult baseStreamResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ChunkParser.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: Can you see an inner exception, that might give you more details. Add the question of there is more info there.

Comment: Also, can you share any more code around this one line, like is it in a using, what does the method it is in look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the code block and Extended properties from call stack. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Are there any recommendation to resolve the error? Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be that you only fetch the `Id`'s of the attachments, iterate over them and download every attachment individually. That requires more requests but every request takes less time. Basically split one big request into multiple smaller requests.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, We had this version of code earlier and due to performance issues we switched to the current approach.